# CSS - center everything within the body tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to center everything within the  tag on the page without adding another container within it.  My situation doesn't allow me to change the markup that is being generated but I am able to edit the CSS.  My overall objective is to create css that allows me to use the zoom tag in IE for the print css (to zoom out), but the way it is currently working, this creates a lot of white space on the right side and I'd like to make sure the content is always centered in the middle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464592/how-to-align-entire-html-body-to-the-center

Answer (score 24):

If you're ok with giving the body a fixed width, you can center it by giving it a width and a margin of `auto` for the left and right margins:

E.g:

```
body { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something like this - http://jsbin.com/emomi3/5/ ...

```
  body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
  }

  body > *  {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  body > script {
    display: none
  }
```

(The borders are just in for illustration purposes)

Comment: Why "position: relative;"?

Answer (score 0):

if you use primefaces ... , I recommend to you to add `!important` like this :

```
body { 
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but I tried this code and use `display: flex;` and it worked:

```
 body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f4eae3;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Give your body tag a fixed width, then set margin to auto. Here is an example:

```css
body {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
```