# align body to center - centering body

Tags: html, css

hi i have a problem with absolute positioning , i want max/min-width/height and centering for page that has background; 
this is my css code but doesent work for centering ... 
i need align body to center with this coditions

css code :

```
body
 {
     position:absolute;
     font-family: "b nazanin","b roya", times new roman;
     font-size:16px;

         min-width:948px;
     min-height:550px;

     width:1280px;
     height:700px;


 }

html
{
     background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari */
     background: fixed -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
     background: fixed -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
     background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
     background: fixed linear-gradient(red, blue);

}
```

Comment: Why would you position:absolute the body? Makes no sense. Anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464592/how-to-align-entire-html-body-to-the-center

Comment: It's fairly unusual to style the html element. Why not apply it to the body?

Comment: @Mörre otherwise min/max width/height doesn't work :\

Comment: @Pippin because body element has max/min for width and height

Comment: all the content sized by percent , If body is not absolute all the page will getting cluttered on resizing

Comment: well min-width is to prevent the children element from being cluttered.

Comment: @user3052570 max height for body is... very strange at best. If you don't need to scroll you can do so without, and if you DO need to scroll you don't gain anything - now the scrollbars are within the abs. pos. body tag, no difference. You seriously need to reevaluate your approach IMHO.

Comment: Why not use a div and position it with `margin: 0 auto;`?

Answer (score 0):

min-width, min-height are used only when width and height is dynamic.

Check it no http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6ZR/8/

```
body {
    font-family:"b nazanin", "b roya", times new roman;
    font-size:16px;
    outline:10px solid white;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:948px;
    min-height:550px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
html {
    background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: fixed -o-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: fixed -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: fixed linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

See if it can help you.

Comment: thank's for yout attention. it doesn't work for me . my bigest problem is the resizing of page cause content in body are sizing by percentage and absoulte positions , that's cause i use absolute for body- otherwise page on resizing getting cluttered

Comment: then why not directly use width:948px;height:550px;?

Comment: so if i use absolute body with directly sizing how can i show body in center of the page for bigger screens ?

Comment: Add this to body,left:50%;margin-left:-474px;

Answer (score 0):

For centering the body, you just need this :

```
body{
     margin:0 auto;
     width:1000px;
}
```

This code works fine and with all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE[7-11], Opera(Presto too)). You not need nothing more (for this aim).
This code is an example. So, maybe you will need to make some (little) adjustment.

You shouldn't use `position:absolute`. This a bad way. Such as Mörre says, it doens't make a sense also to me. And I advice you also to reevaluate your approach.
The `position:absolute` could be useful sometimes but for this case it's totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably better off using a `<div>` instead. Formatting the `<html>` tag is usually discouraged.

CSS:

```
body {
    background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari */
    background: fixed -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: fixed -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: fixed -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: fixed linear-gradient(red, blue);
    border: 0; /* removes the default body border */
    font-family: 'b nazanin', 'b roya', Times New Roman;
    font-size: 18px;
}

div /* replace with the elements class */ {
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto; /* will cause the element to be center aligned */
    /* min-height and min-width are useless with a fixed height and width */
    width: 1280px;
}
```

And if you want a page with the content centered try this:

```
body {
    border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px; /* 960px is probably the max width you would want to use */
}
```

The Html would look like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
```