# How to align iframe always in the center

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment

I have an iframe surrounded by div element and I am simply trying to position it always in the center.
here is my jsfiddle effort :  **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/)**

and trully believe that someone could help because I am sure that it is something really simple but I just can not see it.

Here is the HTML itself:

```
<div id="top-element">Some div that has greater width than the inner div</div>
<div id="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.apple.com/" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 41):

## Center iframe

**Edit**: FLEX solution

Using `display: flex` on the `<div>`

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9gTm/867/

One solution is:

```css
div {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
div > iframe{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9gTm/

**edit**: vertical align added

## css:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
div > iframe{
  width: 200px;
}
div,
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    display: table;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9gTm/1/

Comment: just edited changing the margin auto, since it's not working with iframes, instead use text-align for it

Comment: margin:auto works on iframe if you display it as block :) iframe {display:block;margin:auto;} http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/5/

Comment: Just to really ensure its entered also add: border:0; margin:0; to your body CSS

Comment: Using this, I cannot resize iframe whatsoever. How to achieve that?

Comment: there was an error in the iframe css and just fixed it, thanks @biozalp

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper iframe {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think if you add margin: auto; to the div below it should work.

```
div#iframe-wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is display an iframe on a page, the simplest solution I was able to come up with doesn't require divs or flex stuff is:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And then the HTML is just:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <iframe ...></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

If this is all you need you don't need wrapper divs to do it. This works for text content and stuff, too.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz3pedt1/).

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776179) looks even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use display:table to vertical-align content and text-align:center to horizontal align your iframe.
http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/7/

```
html {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#top-element {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:orange;
    width:100%;
}
#iframe-wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```

version with table-row http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/9/

```
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#top-element {
    display:table-row;
    background:orange;
    width:100%;
}
#iframe-wrapper {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: But when you minimize the window as much as possible, see how the iframe goes beyond the right border of its surrounding div(the orange background on the top)

Comment: add vertical to body padding or vertical- margin to iframe container  to keep a safe area . Else, keep using the the display and display top-element and iframe-container as table-row ... this demo is your hint to see how easy things can be done via idsplay:table/table-cell/table-row and so on.

Comment: @GCyrillius Guys, what I am trying to tell you is that the iframe goes beyond the surrounding it div. Just squeeze the result-window and scroll to the right end and see how it goes beyond the right-border of the orange div.

Comment: oups, sorry, i didnot update the jsfiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/9/ and mistook what you meant, just expecting the defaut of absolute position being shown :)

Comment: @GCyrillius Now it looks pretty well but i don't know if you noticed that in my example on vertical resize a window scroll was not showing but only the iframe scroll was changing. Check that: http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43176/discussion-between-mathinvalidnik-and-gcyrillus)

Answer (score 0):

First **remove `position:absolute`** of `div#iframe-wrapper iframe`, **Remove** `position:fixed` and **all other css** from `div#iframe-wrapper`

**Then apply this css,**

```
div#iframe-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/13/)**

Comment: This just totally doesn't work because it doesn't scroll the iframe itself

Comment: @mathinvalidnik you want to scroll iframe when page is scrolled??

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it is fixed on the window. Plus, it would be nice if the vertical scroll on the window was not showing.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik check my updated answer. check updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and add a container and a style to centre it

```
<style>
.container { 
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
```

After you paste this add a div to the iFrame and then it should look like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <iframe src="embbeded form link here" width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple HTML only way: no css no scripts

```
<center>
<iframe> your content </iframe>
</center>
```

example 2 frame center and text in the frame left or right e.c.t

```
<center>
<iframe align="left|right|middle|top|bottom"> your frame content </iframe>
</center>
```

to see all iframe parameters you can use a iframe generator https://superblogger3.blogspot.com/2023/03/iframe-generator.html