# Centering iframe div

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, center

When coding an iframe to resize with the screen I cannot center it. I tried all the responses from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583088/how-to-align-iframe-always-in-the-center) question but had no luck. Am I missing something obvious or is there no way to do this?

HTML

```
<div class="videoWrap">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/playlist?list=PLn0iVeY0xhgZvWDQ1K_6EChZe_4TL5zDZ"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoWrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrap iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the `iframe` in the `div`? Or the `div` in the screen?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer if you feel one of these solutions helped. People are more likely to help you in the future if they see you have accepted answers.

Comment: @blackandorangecat I am centering the iframe in the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the question you linked...

```css
.videoWrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.videoWrap iframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div, body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrap">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/playlist?list=PLn0iVeY0xhgZvWDQ1K_6EChZe_4TL5zDZ"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This does use `flex` which is not supported in earlier versions of `IE`

Comment: This doesn't work when adding it to a website with multiple divs.

Comment: EDIT: This worked! However 'div,body,html {...}' is not necessary, especially in a website with multiple divs

Comment: @alohomoira I think you're correct - however is is required for the `jsfiddle`. Your website must have the height/width set elsewhere. Anyways, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying margin: auto; css property to your div.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Tried this multiple times before questioning there. Thanks to!

Answer (score 0):

In my example I am centering the wrapper element horizontally and vertically with the usual settings (position: absolute` is applied *here*), and also defining the width and height here. The video itself simply fills the centered wrapper.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.videoWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* 16:9 */
  width: 80vw;
  height: 45vw;
}

.videoWrap iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrap">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/playlist?list=PLn0iVeY0xhgZvWDQ1K_6EChZe_4TL5zDZ"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)`:

```
.videoWrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrap iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: using 'transform:' it resized the video window